# File in use is wiped when there's a power faliure

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, power-management

We are a bunch of folks (9) working on a project. All of us save our files to a single computer which has windows share enabled on the project folder. There are occasionally power cuts in our place and most of the time when a power failure happens, the file which we are currently working on is blank completely after power comes back, even if the file was saved. Due to this all our work gets lost sometimes.

I wanted to ask if there is anything in Ubuntu with which we can buffer the current file in some temp folder or anything similar, some other more stable/reliable method of sharing a project.

Currently we are not in a position to put a ups backup to computers and when power goes, the backup generator takes few seconds to start up again.

To overcome the situation, we fearfully make a backup of the complete folder every hour. The project size is around 3 GB, so it is kind of a pain.

We use different versions of Ubuntu but this scenario is not dependent on version we are using. Also, we use different editors; some use eclipse, I use sublime, but it's not dependent on this either.

Comment: I would suggest you use some sort of version control such as subversion or incremental backups such as rsync. rsync would only copy files that changes, but, honestly, your whole strategy (9 people editing 3 Gb of data at the same time) is the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use some flavour of Linux on the server?

- Using a journaling filesystem on the server should mitigate the issue
  of lost files (Windows has NTFS, Linux has ext3, ext4 and others).
- Using a UPS would be even better in this case as computers tend to break when frequently losing power. There are inexpensive UPS available worldwide.
- Taking full backups isn't a good idea, a good backup solution would implement for example a daily full backup and hourly increments. Solutions that do deduplication don't have this issue. You could also use LVM on the server and take snapshots.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, our linux have ext3 filesystem (default), we are planning for ups backup as there is no other stable way which can keep the file intact after power cut right now.

Comment: Hi, I just posted my question's answer. I think this is the most viable (temporary though) way of preventing this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Our team uses sublime text editor. So, after googling a bit here and there I found out [sublime AutoBackup package](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AutoBackups?&long) and installed it through the package control manager of sublime. This extension/package automatically takes backup of the file user is editing and it is also completely customizable like you can have backup for every second (which we are using) and also the file size of the backup can be controlled. See this [link](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AutoBackups#readme) to understand all the options provided.

I am also now using [autosave package](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/auto-save) with this and till now, not a single file got cleaned away by power failure.

If there is any other suggestion from your side, please leave a comment.

Comment: You said others use eclipse etc. So, it's not a complete answer